# Console.log inside chrome dev tools , in the source tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I was just playing around with jBox.js and i was checking the following lines of code:

```
if (this.options.position[p] == 'center') {
        this.pos[a] += Math.ceil((this.targetDimensions[p] - this.dimensions[p]) / 2);
        return;
}
```

Now the way the code is written before the above code executes the value of `this.pos[a]` is `18` and after the code executes the value of `this.pos[a]` is `25` , In my text editor i can add a `console.log` before and after the if condition and find out, But is the same possible using google dev tools ? Can i `console.log` inside the `source` tab in chrome dev tools ?

I am interested in knowing if i can add a console.log statement in the source tab and than run my code, To see the logs.

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: Do you know about the watched expression feature? You can add `this.pos[a]` to you watched list and put in a break point at the line you first want to read. `console.log` is handy but its not for heavy lifting IMHO. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely check this out - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/devtools#logpoints

This helps to log what you need and it stays even if pages is reloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can "intercept" the execution of javascript code in the source tab.
You can click the line number and when you refresh the page and IF Developer tool is open it will stop at that point. See example attached image. it will pause on **line 24** and then if you switch to console tab, you can then alter any variables you want.

[image]

So in summary, sometimes you don't even need to use console.log()

1. You can make use of breakpoint
2. You can also just put the code **debugger;** and it will stop there. Try this out one.

DevTools is a very useful tool for us, try to learn about its feature to maximize its use.

Comment: how do i physically , in the source console.log before and after a certin line ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `console.log()` in Google Chrome, it's displayed in Developer Tools in Console tab.

Comment: console.log vanishes from the source , once i refresh !

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik did you find any solution to this